# Vscode intellisense for html class names in DOM methods

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Can the intellisense feature in VS Code list/autocomplete the class/tag names available in the projects html files, without having to remember and type out the exact name while using DOM methods such as `document.querySelector("#cta");` in a js file.

Example:

HTML Markup in index.html

```
<div id = "cta">
   <a href="" class="btn">Lorem</a>
</div>
```

Javascript src in script.js

```
const CTA = document.querySelector("#cta");
const BTN = document.querySelector(".btn");
```

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoqsX.gif)

Out of the box I do not have such behavior for the intellisense in VScode, as in the example screenshot above, class names are not available. Is such a feature supported and if so how may I configure the project in vscode to do so?

**Edit**

Certain vscode extensions provide completion of class names if they are defined in the css or scss files. I was interested in the case you wanted to target a class name declared in the html files, but is not declared in the stylesheet/css, and has no defined style.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [this plugin?](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

> A Visual Studio Code extension that provides CSS class name completion
>   for the HTML class attribute based on the definitions found in your
>   workspace or external files referenced through the link element.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, unfortunately I have tried the plugin you have mentioned amongst the various other plugins for vscode which provide intellisense for class names, yet they are limited to working within the html documents themselves ie. they do not work within js documents. Any idea if this is possible?